# Rename the text file

Tags: regex, perl

i have multiple text files with different names in a directory. I want to search for a string in all the text files and if the string found in any text file , i want to rename that text file to ABC.txt

Can anyone help me in doing this perl script.

Comment: Have you happened to try this yourself? It is usually a good idea to show what you've tried... Take a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: If more than one file contains the string, if you're not careful, you'll lose all but the last file, because you can only have one file called `ABC.txt` in a given directory at any one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do what you're looking for.

You should spend some time and figure out how this works.

"i want to rename that text file to ABC.txt"

Hopefully you are aware that you can only have `one` file named `ABC.txt` in the same directory. So I'm making the files: `ABC.txt ABD.txt ABE.txt` and so on...

This is untested BTW...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

use autodie;
use File::Copy;

my $dir = "test-dir";
opendir(my $dh, $dir);
chdir $dir;

my @files = grep { !-d $_ } readdir $dh; 

closedir $dh;

my $new = "ABC";
for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, "<", $file;

    while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        if($line =~ /something/) {
            move($file, "$new.txt"); 
            $new++;
            last;
        }   
    }   
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: You can afford to do `last;` after `$new++;` to stop reading the file after you've found the text.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler missed that, thanks.